# Python.exe works with -v or -h but will not execute a file. What is wrong?

Tags: python, windows

The python programs on Windows have stopped executing scripts.

It *will* run python. For example, I can check the version and get the help text.

I've tried running it from `"c:/User/.../python.exe"`, `py -3, etc.

I've also installed all Windows updates and re-installed python. (from version 3.8 to  3.10.7; same issue for both.)

Also, I've tried it from both power-shell and cmd.

I have tried a variety of scripts, but I have a test.py which just prints something.

Also, I've tried `py -3 -c 'print("Hi")'`. It does not work either.

All of these do not print any diagnostics. I simply get the shell prompt on the next line. I can also tell that the script is not even loaded. For example, if I give a filename that does not exist it does the same thing; no error message. The same occurs if I add a syntax error to the file.

I am seriously stumped. What could cause this?

Comment: Can you please show all the commands you've tried? The second paragraph looks garbled, and it's unclear what things you've tried (fully qualified paths, `py` launcher in various methods, etc.)

Comment: You need to include details on what you commands you ran.  Do not gloss over details as it isn't very clear what you mean by 'does not work'.  Does ```python.exe -V``` work?  Does ```python.exe <scriptname>``` work?  etc..

Comment: I have tried:
`py -3 test.py`
`"C:\Users\YBN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" test.py`
Among other things.

Comment: Yes, `py -3 -V` works (Python 3.10.7). `py -3 -h` prints the help text.

But `py -3 test.py` just returns and prints the shell prompt on the next line.

Comment: How did you install Python on your machine? Conda or a Python download? Which one exactly? I'm a big fan of Miniconda3 myself to install Python on Windows (well, on all architectures, really). It gives you a nice coherently managed environment.

Comment: I installed from python.org.

Comment: I just installed Miniconda3. Here is what happened: I typed: 
`c:\ProgramData\Miniconda32\python.exe test.py` and the result was nothing print, just return to the command prompt:
`c:\Users\YBC\scripts>`

Comment: I just noticed that this laptop may have Windows Insider Program installed. I do not see how that could stop pythin from working. Could it?

Comment: Is there a security setting that would do this?